# Sort by index and column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, datetimeindex

I am trying to sort by an index and column but to no avail.

**Partial dataset**

```
            ID         Element  Data_Value
Date            
2005-01-01  USW00004848 TMIN    0
2005-01-01  USC00207320 TMAX    150
2005-01-01  USC00207320 TMIN    -11
2005-01-01  USW00014833 TMIN    -44
2005-01-01  USW00014833 TMAX    33
```

**index column**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',
               '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',
               '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',
               ...
               '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31',
               '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31',
               '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=165002, freq=None)
```

**My attempt**

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis(df2.index).sort_values(by = [df2.index, 'ID'], ascending = [False, True])
```

***Output from above:*** ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 165002

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis("Date").sort_values(by = ["Date", "ID"], ascending = [False, True])
```

***Output from above:*** KeyError: 'Date'

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(by = [df2.index, 'ID'], ascending = [False, True])
```

***Output from above:*** KeyError: "DatetimeIndex(['2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',\n               '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',\n               '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',\n               ...\n               '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31',\n               '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31',\n               '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=165002, freq=None) not in index"

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(by = ["Date", "ID"], ascending = [False, True])
```

***Output from above:*** KeyError: 'Date'

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(by = [df2.index.Date, 'ID'], ascending = [False, True])
```

***Output from above:*** AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because in last it working nice.

Comment: @jezrael '0.19.2' it is a course assignment and is done on their appointed server environment.

Comment: Added solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last pandas version [0.23+](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.23.0.html?highlight=sort_values#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels) this working nice:

```
print (df2.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-01',
               '2005-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)


df2 = df2.sort_values(by = ["Date", "ID"], ascending = [False, True])
print (df2)
                     ID Element  Data_Value
Date                                       
2005-01-01  USC00207320    TMAX         150
2005-01-01  USC00207320    TMIN         -11
2005-01-01  USW00004848    TMIN           0
2005-01-01  USW00014833    TMIN         -44
2005-01-01  USW00014833    TMAX          33
```

Another solution working also in some oldier pandas versions is convert `DatetimeIndex` to column first, sorting and convert back:

```
df2 = (df2.reset_index()
          .sort_values(by = ["Date", "ID"], ascending = [False, True])
          .set_index('Date'))
```

Thanks @Alexander for alternative:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('ID', append=True)
         .sort_index(ascending=[False, True])
         .reset_index('ID'))

print (df2)
                     ID Element  Data_Value
Date                                       
2005-01-01  USC00207320    TMAX         150
2005-01-01  USC00207320    TMIN         -11
2005-01-01  USW00004848    TMIN           0
2005-01-01  USW00014833    TMIN         -44
2005-01-01  USW00014833    TMAX          33
```

Comment: Alternatively, `df.set_index('ID', append=True).sort_index(ascending=[False, True]).reset_index('ID')`.